# EventCreate.exe creates a "CustomSource" value, what does it mean?

Tags: winapi, event-log, eventlog-source, custom-eventlog

The command-line `EventCreate.exe` tool registers a user-defined event source in the Registry for the Windows Event Log Viewer to use, like this:

```
eventcreate /t INFORMATION /ID 100 /L "Application" /SO [SourceName] /D "Description"
```

[image]

I wrote an app that has its own Event Log resource strings and is registered as an event source, [per MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363661.aspx), but it doesn't use the `CustomSource` value and works fine.

I can't find any documentation on MSDN, or elsewhere online, on what `CustomSource` is meant for exactly.  None of the registered sources on my machines use it.

Does anyone know what `CustomSource` is meant for, and how it works?  Is it just something internal to `EventCreate.exe`, or does the Windows Event Log actually use it for something?

Comment: i search in system32 and subfolders - only *EVENTCREATE.EXE* and *MSI.DLL* containing string `CustomSource` (and look like msi.dll unrelated here). based on this we can guess that this is faster something internal to *EventCreate.exe* - otherwise some another system binary must containing this string for query this value (in not think that it containing in encoded form).

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2013/11/01/eventcreate-and-error-source-parameter-is-used-to-identify-custom-applicationsscripts-only/

Comment: it is definitely just internal to `EventCreate.exe` only

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @RbMm for pointing out this blog article:

[EventCreate and "ERROR: Source parameter is used to identify custom applications/scripts only"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaron_margosis/2013/11/01/eventcreate-and-error-source-parameter-is-used-to-identify-custom-applicationsscripts-only/)

> For whatever reason, EventCreate was designed only to log events that are associated with event log sources that EventCreate created.  **It does this by adding a REG_DWORD value called `CustomSource` in the source's registry key when it creates a new source, and checking for that value for a source that already exists.**  So in the above example, if the "MyStuff" source didn't already exist in the Application log, the above command would have created it and configured its key with a `CustomSource` value.  Subsequent calls to EventCreate with the same source would succeed after verifying the existence of the `CustomSource` value.  If, however, the "MyStuff" source had been created through another mechanism that didn't create a CustomSource flag, such as with the PowerShell `New-EventLog` cmdlet, then you'd get the error message.  If you create a `CustomSource` value in an event source's key, then EventCreate will work with that source.